# Perform backup with MySql-Commandlineclient

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

how to take backup of all table and procedure of project in mysql with the help of command line client

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From OS shell, and not from inside MySQL shell

```
mysqldump --routines <db name> -u<username> -p > backup.sql
```

If you want to save all databases:

```
mysqldump --routes --all-databases -u<username> -p > backup.sql
```

Just as a side note, for security reasons avoid storing plain text password in DB tables, and avoid printing your actual database online ;)

Comment: lets take my shcema name is XYZ and i want to take backup of that schema with the help of command line client.

than which query is executed to create a backup of database in folder

Comment: You may use: 
`mysqldump --routines XYZ -uusername -p > backup.sql`